# What phrase do you use to express “don’t use sth”

Tags: grammar

So 用 means use and 不用 means don’t need to. So what phrase do you use to express don’t use
For example: I don’t use mobile phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, 用 can mean both "don’t need to" and "don't use" depending on context. E.g. 我不用 can mean 我不需要, I don't need it；我不用手机 can mean I don't use mobile phone.